# How can I get all fields with same schema using find()?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the native mongodb node package.
Collection sample:

```
{
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
},
{
  a: 'aa'
}
```

In this case, if I use find(), I will get the exact same as the collection shows.
This is what I want:

```
{
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
},
{
  a: 'aa',
  b: null (or '')
}
```

I tried to use projection to do it but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mongodb $ifNull (aggregation) with $project

```
db.test.aggregate([
      {
          $project: {
             a:1, 
             b: { $ifNull: [ "$b", "null" ] }
          }
       }
   ])
```

output will be

```
{
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
},
{
  a: 'aa',
  b: "null")
}
```